# How do I connect this to my breadboard?

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

I just purchased [this Grove RTC](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove_-_RTC). It includes a cable presumably to connect it to a breadboard and/or Arduino, but the pin holes on this cable are much smaller than those on a breadboard or Arduino.

How/where would I connect this in the case of using an Arduino Uno?

[image]

Comment: If you want a quick temporary solution, you can probably stick 22 gauge wires in that connector, secure with electrical tape and put the other end in your breadboard.

Comment: I would get two jumper wires (with a male plug at each end) chop them into half so you now have four wires, each with a bare end and a plug, strip the wire where it was cut, and solder the 4 bare wires to your socket, and then plug the plugs into the breadboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use jumper wire, or pull the connectors from the Housing and connect them with male connectors.